# wpf e-book pdf including mvvm pattern

Tags: wpf, pdf, mvvm

I need to find a pdf or e-book about wpf that includes mvvm pattern? Can anyone give any advices?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be Josh Smith's Advanced MVVM e-book ($10 on Kindle, $15 on DRM PDF).

More information: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/

Answer (score 1):

[Learn WPF MVVM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M365NCZ) is a quick read and includes everything from WPF basics to MVVM.

You can get [PDF, epub, mobi or online version here](https://leanpub.com/learnwpf).